# manually add boot entry

Tags: windows, multi-boot

I recently had to reinstall windows.  I have 2 hdd's, both with windows installed, but only had to reinstall on one of them.
However now my boot selection screen (to choose which of the hdds/windows to boot to) is gone.  From what I read it's the second install that adds the boot entry, but I really don't want to reinstall the second hdd (all my data is there).
[image]
Here C: is the newly installed windows, and D: is the old/existing windows install.

I have tried a few things but no luck so far:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdboot d:\windows BFSVC Error: Invalid
VolumePathNameLegth d:\windows\ BFSVC Error: Failed to initialize
global state. Status = [c000000d]
```

I have also tried bcdedit /create and /copy but neither fixed the issue.

Comment: Try EasyBCD tool and see if it works for you.https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Answer (score 0):

easybcd helped, but it still wouldnt boot

it seems to be be caused by autopilot

i ended up reloading the drive, then putting it in audit mode